# Can someone help in compile a GTK/PyGObject All-in-one for Python 3.7?

Tags: python, windows, gtk, pygobject, msys2

We used to distribute (for Windows) a very large Python 2/PyGTK application by packaging Python installer itself along other needed installers and packages through an InnoSetup script. Among with those other installers and packages we deliver an all-in-one PyGTK package and it worked very well.

Now we've converted our software for Python 3 and GTK 3. Ok, there is an all-in-one for PyGI [1] (PyGObject Introspection), but just for Python 2.7 to 3.4 and we need at least Python 3.7.

I've spent last couple of weeks learning MSYS2 and trying to understand how MyPaint or Gaphor (which are similar apps) are distributed for Windows without success. I am able to download and install GTK and PyGI using pacman on MSYS2/MingW64 but I cannot figure out how can I create such a package like PyGI all-in-one. I asked for help or instructions on SourceForge but I got no responses so far.

I am asking for help or any clues on how can I generate a PyGI-all-in-one-like installer. Thanks in advance!

[1] https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/

Comment: I think I found my first clue: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/Win32/MSVCCompilationOfGTKStack

Comment: And that is the answer: https://github.com/wingtk/gvsbuild Not a solution for the All-in-One installer I am searching for, but the GTK3 stack can be built. I did not experiment with distributing it yet, but I'll add another comment about this as soon as I can try.

Answer (score 1):

You can bundle a PyGObject app in Windows using [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org). It can be used with either MSYS2 or gvsbuild to find and bundle all the GTK libraries you need. Then you can use your InnoSetup script to create an installer.